# Como alterar a imagem de acordo com uma variável vinda do banco?

Tags: javascript, mysql, html5, jsp, java-bean

Sou principiante nessa parte de `front-end` e fiz uma função que retorna um número inteiro do meu banco de dados MySQL.
Criei 5 imagens, cada uma corresponde a um número retornado do banco e as anexei na minha pasta **imgs** do projeto.

Verifiquei que o valor está sendo passado até a página **JSP** sem problemas, porém gostaria de saber como faço uma função em JavaScript para chamar a imagem de acordo com o número retornado pelo banco e a tag `HTML5` a utilizar no meu código.

Atualmente meu código de JavaScript é esse:

```
  function mudaFoto(status){
         var fotos = ["imgs/panel/img-painel-02-01.png","imgs/panel/img-painel-02-02.png","imgs/panel/img-painel-02-03.png","imgs/panel/img-painel-02-04.png","imgs/panel/img-painel-02-05.png"];
                if(status==1){
                         document.getElementById("icone").src=fotos[0];
                }
                else{
                if(status==2){
                    document.getElementById("icone").src=fotos[1];
                }
                else{
                if(status==3){
                    document.getElementById("icone").src=fotos[2];
                }
                else{
                if(status==4){
                    document.getElementById("icone").src=fotos[3];
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("icone").src=fotos[4];
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Meu código no HTML:

```
< img id="icone" img="imgs/panel/img-painel-02-01.png" alt="imagem de status" class="img-responsive" />
```

Comment: altere o atributo "img" da sua <img> para "src" !

Answer (score 1):

A sua função  `mudaFoto(status)` está OK.

Na sua tag img falta o atributo src

```
<img id="icone" src="imgs/panel/img-painel-02-01.png" img="imgs/panel/img-painel-02-01.png" alt="imagem de status" class="img-responsive" />
```

> Você pode usar evento **onload** diretamente na sua função ou na tag `<body>` (versões modernas de Javascript também aceitam outros elementos como por exemplo na tag `<img>`).

exemplos:

- Direto na função

  ```
   window.onload = function mudaFoto(status){ 
   .................
   .................
  ```
- Na tag img

  ```
  <img id="icone" ..... onload="mudaFoto(numeroDoBanco)" />
  ```
- Na tag body

  ```
  <body onload="mudaFoto(numeroDoBanco)">
  ```